# Can I hit with Ahri's Q more than twice?

Tags: league-of-legends

I've seen Draven's Whirling Death will achieve a third hit if you flash over your ult to change its course to hit the enemy a third time. A variant with Blitzcrank can be seen [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ob1ANn005x0%E2%80%8E/%22here%22) and the usage of 'teleport' [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mFTyKHPUTOQ%E2%80%8E/%22here%22)

> (Active): Draven hurls two massive axes in a given direction, dealing physical damage to every unit struck.
>    Upon reaching the edge of the map, striking an enemy champion or upon the reactivation of Whirling Death, the axes will slowly come to a stop before changing direction and returning to Draven

Ahri's Q is another out-and-back ability similar to Draven's ult.

> (Active) Ahri sends out and pulls back her orb, dealing magic damage on the way out and true damage on the way back.

My question is, if you are able to flash over your enemy with Orb of Deception in flight, causing it to change direction, **will it hit a third time? Will it deal magic or true damage on the third hit?**

Comment: Good question. It would be almost impossible to pull off because flash has a relatively short range now and you will have to be close to your opponent but at the same time wait until the last moment because the ball (for ahri) will have to be returning and to have already hit him on its way back which will practically mean it will be really close to you when you flash. but if its valid then it means double true damage for ahri.. :O

Comment: Not to be a spoil, but can you post any solid evidence of that? All I found after googling was rather questionable evidence. Besides, if Draven/Ahri can flash to make their skills hit 3 times, then the opponent in question should also be able to flash for a third hit, which is MUCH easier to accomplish and should really happen on a regular basis even in real games. I tend to not believe this until I see it, because all these skills are programmed to hit only the intended number of times. For example you can't get hit twice by Ezreal ult by flashing into it again.

Comment: @Hackworth But that is not question, if for example the enemy gets hit, then gets hit on the return and then flashes for another hit the 2 last ones will be true damage. The question here is when he flashes the direction the orb is flying essentially changes direction. It might be that the code sais that forwards hit is normal and backwards hit is true damage, then it could be normal, true, normal. Or if it just takes the return that it would be normal, true, true.

Comment: @Hackworth desperation posted a question, not a fact. So you can't really ask for solid evidence when solid evidence is what desperation seeks in the first place... :S It's an interesting thought nevertheless. Ezeals Ultimate is a very fast projectile. I'm not sure you can flash in time to actually get hit a second time. an easier-to-test trick would be to get Teleport - Make an Ezreal shoot you in the face near his base with his ult and then teleport back to your base and wait for his ultimate to hit you a second time. THAT would be an easy test to see if you can get hit a second time by it.

Comment: You need to work on your reading comprehension. The question is the sentence that is ended by the question mark, whether Ahri Q will deal magic or true damage on the theoretical 3rd hit. He said that **"It is comfirmed that some ults such as draven's whirling death will achieve a third hit if you flash over your ult to change it's course to hit the enemy a third time."**. That is a statement, not a question. And if he claims it is confirmed, then all I want to know is his source, because based on my experience, I don't believe it right now.

Comment: @Hackworth,edited my question with the video link.

Comment: uhm how does that video prove a triple hit on draven ult? That was a regular double hit on the first enemy minion, one for each direction just as the ult is designed to.

Comment: Yeah that's the questionable evidence I was talking about - that wasn't a third hit, it was the Blitzcrank Q that dealt damage. It was close, but the center of the returning draven ult did not yet hit the Nidalee before she was pulled away. So the damage order was ult - Blitz Q - returning ult.

Comment: there are substantial other videos that demonstrate this under the 'draven ultimate triple hit' title.I just picked one hastily xP

Comment: @desperation did you pick one hastily out of... desperation?  (it's punny because its your user name)  All bad jokes aside, could you find another? I'm interested in seeing this in action too

Comment: By all means, please post them, I would love to see the evidence, no irony. I want to learn as much as you do, and that would be something new.

Comment: lol indeed. You "let" *us* do the work to prove *your* point when it's called into question. Your last edit was 17 minutes ago, you can't ff before 20.

Comment: I remember using this trick way back in beta with sivir, when it was easier because flash had way more range. It's definitly possible and it left me baffled into HOW and WHY they programmed it that way because as a developer, the easiest most relilable way to programm these kind of spells wouldnt allow these 3rd hits.

Comment: @YallaT. Beta is beta and is also long gone - the only relevant question is whether or not it would still work today, which is what I strongly doubt. And no, as a developer myself, it would obviously be easier to implement a projectile that does *not* have to remember how often it has hit a certain target. Which is probably the reason why that bug existed in the first place.

Comment: I doubt that the game Engine and how the spells are designed have changed since then. I have no way to test this right now.

Comment: I really want to go and test anivia's Q again after reading all of these comments. I know that before it was possible to hit a champion three times with her Q(if they had just the right amount of move speed and were running in the direction the ball was traveling) but I don't know if they changed this or if it's just not possible anymore(I think they may have raised the projectile speed of Q)

Comment: would be great if someone actually demonstrated this with ...... AHRI Q.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It is not possible for an ability to hit more often than it was designed to - if it does, it's a bug.**

As you can see in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IuXG5GTPhpA), Ezreal's ult can hit the same target only once. Another example would be Veigar's Even Horizon - if the target manages to break the stun quickly enough to walk through the same Event Horizon, he will not be stunned again. Accordingly, it should be impossible to be hit more than twice by returning projectile abilities such as Ahri's Q, Sivir's Q, or Draven's ult.

Comment: I know for a fact that Sivir's Q only hits twice even if you perform fancy tricks with flash and such. I have to imagine other similar abilities work the same way.

Comment: I just tested Ezreal's ult and it can't in fact hit more than once. So since it doesn't say anything in the description (about hitting only once) and judging from riots policies so far I suppose its a general rule. So I agree 100% with Hackworth.

Comment: @StrixVaria That is because Sivir's Q description sais : Sivir hurls her crossblade to a target location, which then returns to her. Enemies in its path take physical damage, with 20% reduced damage to each subsequent target. Each enemy can be damaged only twice. The others don't say that, Ezreals sais that it does damage to the players it passes through so I would guess once it passes through it doesn't count anymore. EZ's ult is also different in the fact that it doesn't come back, so 2 times damage would never be implemented for the spell.

Comment: @Lyrion The ability to hit twice would probably be the default behavior, rather than something unusual, just because it's easier to code that way. One thing Ezreal and Sivir do is reduce the damage depending on the number of enemies hit, so the spells already need to track hits in some way.

Answer (score 1):

It will do true damage as the orb is on its way back, you just change the position where YOU are, but its still on the way to you.
The number of hits has nothing to do with the kind of damge it deals, only the direction it is heading.